# How do I setup a dyn-dns like service with a Custom domain?

Tags: dns, dreamhost

Simply put, I have a domain xyz.com, 
I want pc.xyz.com to point to my pc IP (which is dynamic)

any available solutions?

I need a Mac client to update the changing IP, and a service to run on my domain to get those updates.

Something like http://www.dyndns.com/

( I have a domain from Dreamhost if that helps..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a CNAME entry so that pc.xyz.com is an alias to a dyndns name. I know that doesn't strictly answer the question of how to run a dyndns-like service yourself, but it will achieve the effect you described with a minimum of effort.

Answer (score 1):

[How to set up DNS service dynamic / static](http://www.aboutdebian.com/dns.htm) is a good place to start.  Technically, the concepts are not difficult, but much easier if you use a DNS server that is able to use MySQL or some other database.  For example:  [MySQL BIND SDB Driver](http://mysql-bind.sourceforge.net/) ...

> The project was started so that we could automatically create sub-domains for user's homepages on account creation.

By far this is the easiest approach and allows you to write a very thin client that can send a quick web request to your system to update the DNS based on your new IP ... Maybe even build your own REST API ...

Comment: I've donne something like that using php to get the computer IP and then some cpanel hacks to change the IP on record. It work... well... dyndns suffer from less cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `cron` (or, since you're using a Mac, `launchd`) and the DreamHost API to achieve the result you want, as [described here](http://blog.lassey.us/2011/04/12/roll-your-own-dyndns-with-dreamhosts-apis/).